# Multiplicar dos arrays en C#

Tags: c#, array

Tengo que resolver lo siguiente: Crear dos arrays de 5 posiciones cargados con valores aleatorios, y luego multiplicar cada posición del primer array por todas las posiciones del segundo array, recorrer las 5 posiciones, almacenar cada resultado en un array nuevo y mostrar en pantalla.

La consigna daba un ejemplo asi

```
Array 1: 2 3 6 8 9 
Array 2: 6 9 7 1 3 
Resultado: 2268 xxxx xxxx xxxx
```

Lo que debía hacer era 2x6x9x7x1x3 / 3x6x9x7x1x3 / etc etc y guardar los resultados en un array nuevo para luego mostrarlo.

Hasta el momento solo pude lograr lo que muestro en el codigo:

```
        int[] array1 = new int[5];
        int[] array2 = new int[5];
        int[] array3 = new int[5];
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Carga de numeros aleatorios en los arrays.
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            array1[a] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            array2[a] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }

        // Muestra en pantalla de los array con los numeros cargados.
        Console.Write("Array 1: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(array1[a] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n\nArray 2: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(array2[a] + " ");
        }

        Console.Write("\n\nArray 3: ");
        // Multiplicacion de cada posicion del primer array con todas las posiciones del segundo
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            array3[a] = array1[a] * array2[a];
            Console.Write(array3[a] + " ");
        }
```

Evidentemente la última parte la estoy haciendo super mal, alguna manito por ahi, lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: ¿Por que no usas un matriz de 2 dimensiones en vez de un vector?

Comment: Porque el profesor de la facultad, me lo pide con arrays en la consigna. Y normalmente pide que respetemos la consigna de lo que se pide

Comment: la pregunta no esta bien clara. que es lo que quieres exactamente. ¿Quieres multiplicar cada elemento del primer array por los 5 elementos del segundo array el obtener todo el resultado o lo que quieres es multiplicar un elemento del primer array con el elemento del segundo array y luego sumar la siguiente multiplicación?
¿o lo que quieres es imprimir cada multiplicación? porque este ultimo caso el array tres necesitas 25 posiciones y no 5.

Comment: Disculpa por las demoras, estuve sin conexion a internet... Bien, tambien disculpen si no me supe expresar..

La consigna daba un ejemplo asi
Array 1: 2 3 6 8 9
Array 2: 6 9 7 1 3
Resultado: 2268 xxxx xxxx xxxx

lo que debia hacer era 2x6x9x7x1x3 / 3x6x9x7x1x3 / etc etc y guardar los resultados en un array nuevo para luego mostrarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] array1 = new int[5];
        int[] array2 = new int[5];
        int[] array3 = new int[5];
        
        Random rnd = new Random();

        // Carga de numeros aleatorios en los arrays.
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            array1[a] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
            array2[a] = rnd.Next(1, 10);
        }

        // Muestra en pantalla de los array con los numeros cargados.
        Console.Write("Array 1: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(array1[a] + " ");
        }
        Console.Write("\n\nArray 2: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(array2[a] + " ");
        }
        
        // multiplicar los arrays
        // se usa un for anidado, el primer for recorre el array1 y el segundo for el array2
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            // la variable res contiene el valor en posicion i del array1, servirá para
            // acumular el valor de las multiplicaciones
            int res = array1[i];
            
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                // se multiplica el elemento i del array1 con el elemento j del array2
                // y se almacena el resultado en res
                res *= array2[j];
            }
            // se asigna el valor de res a array3 en posicion i
            array3[i] = res;
        }
        
        Console.Write("\n\nArray3: ");
        for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++)
        {
            Console.Write(array3[a] + " ");
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias de corazón, me imaginaba un for anidado, pero no sabia como y que valores asignar... Muchisimas gracias

Disculpa por las demoras, estuve sin conexion a internet...

Answer (score 0):

No encuentro claro el ejercicio, pero entiendo que deberías multiplicar el valor de la primera posición del primer array por todos los valores del segundo, por ejemplo:
Array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
Array2 = [1,2,3,4,5]

Resultado = [15, 30, 45, 61, 75] ; Obviamente los arreglos se hacen con valores Random.

Si este es el caso solo debes implementar el siguiente bucle.

```
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ ){
            acum = 0;
            for ( j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++ ){
                    acum = acum + Array1[i] * Array2[j];    
            }
            Array3[i] = acum;
    }
```

Esto sería la implementación que debes hacer compañero. Saludos, agradecería tu comentario

Comment: Disculpa por las demoras, estuve sin conexion a internet...Exactamente asi, como exprese con el otro compañero que tambien facilito una solucion.

Les agradezco a ambos por tener las ganas de colaborar, aun me cuesta encontrar las soluciones simples a los algortimos, siento que busco otras vueltas y no como deberia. Muchisimas gracias a todos!